# Qt Cmake компиляция. Как включить network в qt 7 при cmake сборке?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, кроссплатформенность

Код в CMakeLists.txt следующий:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(untitled21 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
#find_package(Qt7Network REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Network, {QT_QTNETWORK_LIBRARY})
add_executable(untitled21
   main.cpp,
   worker.h
)
target_link_libraries(untitled21 Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core)
```

а потом ошибка:
Cannot specify link libraries for target "untitled21" which is not built by this project.
как включить network в CMakeLists.txt в qt7?

Comment: `target_link_libraries` должно находится *после* объявления библиотеки или исполняемого файла, а не до

Comment: я поменял target_link_libraries в конец, ошибка показывает на find_package

Comment: *ошибка показывает на find_package* - в вопросе этого нет

Comment: понял, спс я исправил